# Trouble centering and dynamically resizing image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, resize

Usually I'm able to figure things out given enough time (hence my first post here), but I've been beating my head against the wall for a while now on this one.

I'm trying to:

1. Center image using jQuery (it's an `<img>` tag, not background image on a `<div>`),
2. Load the correct image size on (window).load, and
3. Load a new img file at certain breakpoints as the window is re-sized.

Here is my current attempt.  The centering script works perfectly.  Also, the correct image file is loaded.  However, I cannot get the re-size portion to work when the window is made wider or narrower (the image file does not dynamically reload).

CODE:

```
  <!-- Center Floating Div Elements -->
  <script> 
    jQuery.fn.center = function () {
      this.css("position","absolute");
      this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
      return this;
    }

    $(window).load(function(){
     $('.laptop').center();
     window.onresize = function(event) {
      $('.laptop').center();
    }
  });
  </script>

  <!-- Load correct image size on window load -->
  <script>
    $(function(){
      if($(window).width() >= 0 && $(window).width() <= 900){
       $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-900.png");
     }
     else if($(window).width() > 900 && $(window).width() <= 1400){
       $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-1500.png"); 
     }
     else{
       $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-2100.png"); 
     }
   })
  </script>

  <!-- Re-load new image size on window resize -->
  <script>
    $(window).onresize = function(){
      if($(window).width() >= 0 && $(window).width() <= 900){
       $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-900.png");
     }
     else if($(window).width() > 900 && $(window).width() <= 1400){
       $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-1500.png"); 
     }
     else{
       $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-2100.png"); 
     }
   });

  </script>
```

The relevant HTML is just a  tag with a class of "laptop", wrapping around an image tag (which is where I want the image source to dynamically change).

lharby: here was my attempt at your suggestion, couldn't get it to work either:

```
<script>
var picresize = $(function(){
        if($(window).width() >= 0 && $(window).width() <= 900){
           $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-900.png");
        }
        else if($(window).width() > 900 && $(window).width() <= 1400){
           $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-1500.png"); 
        }
        else{
           $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-2100.png"); 
        }
    });

    $(window).load(function(){
         $picresize();
         window.onresize = function(event) {
          $picresize();
        }
      });
</script>
```

Comment: If you don't know how to properly format your question, let somebody else do it.

Comment: You could create a single function for showing the different sized images and then bind that function inside various events. So chImg = function(){};
And then $(window).on("load resize", function(){ 
   chImg();
});

Comment: I believe that is achievable with pure css.

Comment: What part of the question was improperly formatted?  I'll edit it right away.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: lharby, I tried that: <script>
var picresize = $(function(){
        if($(window).width() >= 0 && $(window).width() <= 900){
           $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-900.png");
        }
        else if($(window).width() > 900 && $(window).width() <= 1400){
           $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-1500.png"); 
        }
        else{
           $("img").attr("src","/images/laptop-2100.png"); 
        }
    });

    $(window).load(function(){
         $picresize();
         window.onresize = function(event) {
          $picresize();
        }
      });
</script>

Comment: Plus the centering should be possible only with css, so you can lighten the load on what your javascript is doing.

Comment: Stick it in a jsfiddle, I would.

Comment: lharby, I tried that, see my edit to the question.  Couldn't get that way to work either.  kidwon, I tried working it with pure css, but using jQuery actually gives it a really cool effect.  The image is sitting on top of a background cover image, and because it does not resize exactly with the window (width: 100%), it seems to "float" in above the background and stylistically works really well.

Comment: Good call on the jsfiddle, gimme a sec.  Thanks for all the help guys.  Also, I realized posting code in my comment wasn't the best way to respond: see my edited original question lharby.  Thanks again.

Comment: `$picresize()` isn't defined. if you write `var picresize = ...` then it is `picresize()` if you write `var $picresize = ...` then it would be `$picreisze()`

Comment: I made a start here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/5p2xdnaf/ img src is not being set on load at present.

Comment: Boom lharby!  Nice.  Integrated that code and it's really close.  Only issue I'm having is that it seems like the image size code is firing before the centering code does its thing.  So when I load the page, the correct image size loads, but it's not centered.  When I mess with the window width the image centers itself and resizes perfectly though!  I think I need to add a (window).load to the image size code so it waits to fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to elaborate on the comments. I made this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/5p2xdnaf/

There is now a single function called chImage which checks window width and can then be triggered on various events.

I've also stored window width in a variable to make the code a bit cleaner and easier to read (you could also set your sizes in variables, and then change them later if needed, so only write them once).

```
var chImage = function(){
   var winWidth = $(window).width();
   if(winWidth >= 0 && winWidth <= 900){
      $("img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/350x150");
    }
    else if(winWidth > 900 && winWidth <= 1400){
      $("img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/500x300"); 
    }
    else{
      $("img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/800x400"); 
    }
};
```

Then call this function and bind it to whatever events we want.

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
   chImage(); 
});
```

EDIT

I did move the centering function below to make sure it wasn't intefering with this function, but the centering can be achieved with css. I will try and update.

Comment: This is awesome lharby, thank you again.  Looking at the developer tools for the code, it seems like the issue when I load the window is that the centering javascript is firing before the image loads - which means it is taking the window width and subtracting 0 from it.  The result is the image is half visible, shifted to the far right.  When I resize the image the code works perfectly, which makes sense, because the image is fully loaded so the formula works.  How do I make the script wait until the image is loaded to fire?

Comment: Check: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/5p2xdnaf/6/ but also see the answer below regarding css.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Coyier has made an utterly interesting article about [figuring out responsive images](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/133-figuring-responsive-images/).

The image centering can be done in CSS, no need for scripts. See [centering things](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center) and [solved by flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/).

Comment: Thanks, Chris Coyier's article was fantastic.